# how to keep ordering after spread

Tags: r, spread

I would like to know how to keep ordering after spread.

```
data<-tibble(var=c("A","C","D","B"), score=c(1,2,4,3))

data_spread <-data%>%spread(key = var, value = score)
```

I would like to keep the order of c("A","C","D","B").

Answer (score 8):

An option is to convert to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements of 'var' will make sure the `order` is the order of occurrence

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
      mutate(var = factor(var, levels = unique(var))) %>%
      spread(var, score)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#      A     C     D     B
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     4     3
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!